# Login modules for asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I worked in a java based project in which we used LDAP authentication module for Login.
Can I use such any such (easy-to-use) login modules for asp applications.

1) I am individually developing an asp.net application in localhost. I need suggestions about how to implement login functionality.

2) I also need suggestions about how to define database tables related to login.
I initially thought of having a table USER with two columns user_id and password.

3) If I want to save password in an encrypted format, how do I implement the whole functionality. (like login validate, save password at registration)

Thanks,

Comment: You should have to use/configure [Form-based authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication) system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick solution**: Add 'Login' Control from toolbox & use "Web Site Administration Tool" to with it as suggested by @AVD.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa0wsyf(v=vs.100).aspx

**Conceptual/Custom Solution**:

1. Add 'Login' Control from toolbox & Convert it to template using
   smart-tag.
2. Well, the idea "a table USER with two columns user_id and password"
       is simple & good, go with it.
3. DES Encryption:

   ```
       using System.Security.Cryptography;
   static byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("!)@(#*$&"); //Encrypt Key
   static byte[] IV= ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("qwertyui"); //Initial Value
   protected void Encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPwd.Text))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("The string which needs to be encrypted can not be null.");
       } 
       DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, 
           cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
       writer.Write(txtPwd.Text);
       writer.Flush();
       cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
       writer.Flush();
       txtPwd.Text= Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
   }

   protected void Decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPwd.Text))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException
              ("The string which needs to be decrypted can not be null.");
       }
       DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream
               (Convert.FromBase64String(TextBox1.Text));
       CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
           cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
       txtPwd.Text=reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

And the various MembershipProviders. The SqlMembershipProvider contains best practice implementations and the new SimpleMembership aids OpenID and OAuth integration.

On SimpleMembership http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx